# Is there an issue with pandoc's handling of fenced code blocks?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong (I'm not very experienced with markdown) but I have an .md file as such:

```
Here is some code:
~~~bash
my_command arg1 arg2
~~~
```

I'd like pandoc to recognize the fenced code block with github syntax, so I'm using this command:
`pandoc -f markdown_github+fenced_code_blocks+fenced_code_attributes -t html -s`
But pandoc doesn't recognize the code block. This is the output I get:

```
Here is some code:

~bash

my_command arg1 arg2

~
```

If I add a newline before the code block it does work:

```
Here is some code:

~~~bash
my_command arg1 arg2
~~~
```

The proper output:

```
Here is some code:

my_command arg1 arg2
```

If I try my original .md file in GitHub, it's recognized as is. Is there some option in pandoc that I'm missing to make my original .md work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc's `fenced_code_blocks` extension requires an empty lines. From [the manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced-code-blocks):

> Like regular code blocks, fenced code blocks must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.

Moreover, the `github_markdown` reader in pandoc is not an independent reader (there are only [markdown and Common Mark readers](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/tree/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Readers)): it is merely [reading regular markdown with some default extensions](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Extensions.hs#L226), different from the regular pandoc-flavoured markdown reader.

This means that even when writing in github markdown, you have to abide by this rule. I don't see a way around it except preprocessing the file to add a newline before compilation.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I think I'll give [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) a try. Thanks for the clarification though.